# Создание запароленных файлов

Tags: cocoa, macos, xcode, objective-c

Здравствуйте! 
Возможно ли в Cocoa создать запароленный текстовый файл (.txt)? Если нет, то, может, есть возможность создать запароленную папку или архив? Если да, хотелось бы узнать, как это осуществить.

Comment: типичный вопрос типичного iOS девелопера - ничего личного :)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, вам надо посмотреть возможности SQLite.

Comment: @Yogan, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki